# write in pandas row wise

Tags: python, pandas, csv

**My code:**

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        df = pd.read_csv('test - Sheet1 (6).csv') 

        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            df['new']=preprocessing(row['prev'])
        df.to_csv('today.csv',header=False)
```

I have some values in my CSV file like this in prev column-

```
prev
ABC
Abc
BaC
```

I have pre-processing function that will change the column something like this-

```
new
abc
abc
bac
```

But when I am writing it to CSV file, the output I am getting is -

| prev | new |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | bac |
| Abc | bac |
| BaC | bac |

it's only storing the last row value. How do I make it like this-

| prev | new |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | abc |
| Abc | abc |
| BaC | bac |

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the loop, just use `apply`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test - Sheet1 (6).csv') 

df['new'] = row['prev'].apply(preprocessing)
df.to_csv('today.csv', header=False)
```

Iterating through and assigning assigns to the whole column at once, not to that specific index, if you want `iterrows` try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test - Sheet1 (6).csv') 
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index, 'new'] = preprocessing(row['prev'])
df.to_csv('today.csv', header=False)
```